# Whats the easier method to overlay an image with a banner?

Tags: images, background, overlay

I understand its gonna be a longshot in what im asking, however, is there any method that is going to remove the product background + add a banner overlay in an extremely easy method? It doesnt have to look good. Thank you!

*The banner is always the same and wont change

[image: Before Banner Overlay]

[image: After banner overlay]

Comment: Hi. What software are you using?  Usually you would use masking to remove a background from an image, i.e. make a selection, of the object and use the selection as a mask.  Is the second image what you are trying to achieve?  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/161262/edit) and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Photoshop, put the product image on a new layer, set layer opacity to multiply and use a large soft brush with the eraser tool, to clean up some of the light gray on the sides.

The slower, potentially cleaner version, which would remove every bit of shading around the product, would be to create a layer mask, tracing the product shape and removing everything outside the mask.

If you don't use Photoshop, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a easier method instead of using photoshop as it will be time consuming as i have alot of these images :(

Comment: Anything else will be time consuming too. An easier method is to hire somebody on Fiverr, and I'm sure you can get a good deal for a repetitive task like this and you can pay them for 10, 50, 100 image batches, etc.

Comment: @JarettiLoi - you should add that information to your question. It's an important deatail. Otherwise you will get answers you don't want.  There are also ways to semi automate selections of objects in Photoshop and other software like GIMP - but there is no software that can do it all automatically.  It might also help to show what you have already tried. Please edit your question.

Comment: In Photoshop specifically there's the automated function: Select > Subject - then you can add a layer mask.

Comment: If the OP were to mask it and then create an alpha channel with that mask, that mask will be 1) saved in either PSD or TIFF format and; 2) easily recalled using ctrl+click ont he alpha mask in order to use it for other purposes. A TIFF with alpha can even be used in an automated process using e.g. imagemagik to composite it. I do this with "display-to-scale" images of paintings in their frames. Tracing a mask on the sample image is probably 2 mins tops. The alpha channel is essentially a saved selection

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't have to look good

If you do not really care how it looks, do not remove the shadow (In fact It will look better) So the logic is no more "paste the product on your banner".

The logic now is to paste the overlay... over the product.

And prepare an action, yes. On Photoshop.

Comment: I think you're assuming too much; that the OP has the photo in some format with transparency; that the resize will be always the same… & more actual knowledge of how the task will be achieved at all, including Ps ownership & knowing how to write Actions. tbh, these days you can do this task on an iPhone or iPad if absolute quality isn't an issue.